# Using AngularJS to set the height of the elements to the one with the greatest

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Right now I'm using Bootstrap to control the rows and cols; however, there's a problem I can't seem to fully overcome. First off the contents of these components vary in height for not just each component but it's also relative to the user. The width is controlled though using the 'col-*' classes provided by bootstrap:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4" ng-repeat="account in accounts">
    <div class="panel panel-success">
```

However, because the contents vary in size, the height of the component also varies and then these components seem to float around randomly.

I've attempted adding this jQuery code here to "cooperate" with Angular

```
var maxHeight = 0;
$('.panel').each(function() {
    if($(this).height() > maxHeight) maxHeight = $(this).height();
});
$('.panel').height(maxHeight);
```

Yet again Angular isn't fully loaded on the `$(document).ready(fnt()....);` (of course) so I had to set a timeout of 1 sec which appeared to work for me. However, I will get some complaints that it sometimes still does the float (I'm guessing one second isn't sufficient enough for them).

So I'm wondering if there's a way to do this in AngularJS ? To my understanding this will be done in a directive instead of the controller, but it's only to my limited knowledge that I am unaware of obtaining a "maxHeight" of the components.

If there isn't a way to do this in AngularJS I'm open to other ways that would still patch the problem.
Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
Here's an image to better explain my problem
[image: Showing the float error]

As you can see, the divs are brushing up and leaving spaces where they should be, but if they were all set to the same height that would prevent this.

Comment: numerous modules already available to do this. If you want to do it yourself need to trigger it from `$last` property of `ng-repeat` child scope from inside a directive

Comment: Depending on what browsers you need to support, you can always use `display: flex;` to achieve equal height columns.

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for your response but according to the AngularJS API it says that the `$last` property is only to determine if it is the last iteration was this what you were talking about? If so, that would only work if the component with the greatest height was at the end, right?

Comment: @CalebWilliams That would be an easy solution; unfortunately I believe that it only works if there's a parent that wraps the individual rows, if I'm not mistaken? Regardless, I've attempted adding the css attribute to the wrapper , the panel as well as both, with no success

Comment: I think that you would need a wrapper with `display: flex;` and then just use `flex: 1;` on all of the columns. That should take care of the columns. Also, using jQuery with AngularJS is generally considered not a best practice.

Comment: @CalebWilliams I'm aware that you shouldn't use jQuery with AngularJS, that's why I'm looking for an alternative solution :/. Performing flex doesn't seem to change the outcome and seems to make it worse as it'll squish all of components to try and fit all on one row